# SwiftUI get position in Foreach

Tags: foreach, swiftui

I am relatively new to SwiftUI, and I have come across a problem.

I have build this struct for my array:

```
struct Outfit:Identifiable {
   var id = UUID()
   var user: String
   var amount: Double
   var rating: Double
}
```

and I can print all the information I need out with:

```
ForEach(loader.outfitcards) { index  in
   // I need to know if it is the first, second, etc. time it runs
}
```

But I need to know inside the array how many times the array has already run.
I have already tried a @state variable at and then inside the array +1 but Swiftui won't let me do that since that is not a view. Can anyone help me? I also can't get indices() or enumerated() to work and I cant use the ID in the struct because that is not a range or int object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.enumerated()`, with the `id` as `\.element.id`.

```
ForEach(Array(loader.outfitcards.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { (index: Int, outfit: Outfit) in
    /* ... */
}
```